# perforce: create a local backup of current pendinglist

Tags: perforce

in perforce, i have a pending list with some changed files. now i want to revert to the base, but without loosing my changes, so i want to back them up somewhere. like saving the DIFFs of each file. at a later time, i want to restore those changes and continue my work.

is this possible? if so, how?

thanks!

Answer (score 7):

there is no need for external tools at all, assuming you are on a unix machine (or have a proper cygwin setup under Windows, haven't tested it.) The only caveat is that Perforce's `p4 diff` produces an output that is slightly incompatible with `patch`, therefore you need it to point to your unix diff-command. In your client-root you can do

```
P4DIFF=/usr/bin/diff p4 diff -du > pending-changes.patch
```

optional (if you want to revert the open files from the command-line, otherwise use p4v):

```
p4 revert `p4 opened|awk -F\# '{print $1}'`
```

Later you would open the files for edit (can be automated by extracting the affected files from the patchfile `pending-changes.patch` and then:

```
patch < pending-patches
```

Depending on your path-layout in your client-root, you have to use the `-p#num` option of patch to get the patch applied cleanly.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do a shelve.  It's a way of saving a changelist for future editing.  The link below is a Python add-in for Perforce that implements shelve.  Also, I know that Practical Perforce has a couple of ways to shelve current changes without an external script.  I don't have the book in front of me but I'll try to update this question tonight when I do.

http://public.perforce.com/wiki/P4_Shelve

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to look at that book?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.  Unfortunately, it looks like my book got left with a previous employer when I left there.  However, the two ways are listed in the Google Books preview below.  It looks like a sparse branch would be the way to go for the original poster.

http://books.google.com/books?id=tlZHxJ5dkGcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=practical+perforce#v=onepage&q=shelve&f=false

Answer (score 5):

Linked to from P4Shelve, is [P4tar](http://public.perforce.com/wiki/P4tar) which looks very useful, and does the operations on the client, rather than branching on the server.

Certainly I'll be looking into doing similar things soon.

Answer (score 2):

See also this question:

[Sending my changelist to someone else without checking in.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373234/how-can-i-grab-my-local-changelist-and-send-it-to-someone-else-in-perforce)

It's basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a branch of these files in some appropriate location
- Check out the branch versions of the files you have edited
- Copy the edited files over from the trunk and submit them
- Revert the files on the trunk

Now you've got those "diffs" you wanted safely archived.  When your ready to apply those changes later on, just integrate them back into the trunk.

This is what the Python script, that [Brett mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722240/perforce-create-a-local-backup-of-current-pendinglist/1722322#1722322), does.  This is the way to do it manually without any special tools.